# Java Thread seems to be paused when the display turns off in win10

Tags: java, windows-10

for example:

- windows10
- jdk8

Steps to reproduce:

1. (windows10) Change Turn Off Display After Time to 1 minute
2. Run the following code.  (This needs to be wrapped in a Java class.)

   ```
   Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
       while (true) {
           System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().format(
                              DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
           try {
               Thread.sleep(10000);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   });
   t.start();
   ```
3. wait few minutes
4. wake up screen

output

```
2021-02-27T14:13:56.58
2021-02-27T14:14:06.59
2021-02-27T14:14:16.59
2021-02-27T14:14:26.59
2021-02-27T14:14:36.59
2021-02-27T14:14:46.591
**2021-02-27T14:14:56.592
2021-02-27T14:15:58.345**
2021-02-27T14:16:08.346
```

is there any way to keep thread running while the display power is off?

Comment: I don't think what you say makes sense if display is off, as long as your cpu is running. May be you are confused with the thread sleep duration?

Comment: @raj240 yes.Im trying to find out the reason of  why sleep duration changed. but when display is on it works well

Comment: because the sleep duration is not strictly honoured, its the minimum duration. This might go up for multiple reasons, even the OS could be the reason behind, depending on what other processes are running behind apart from your JVM.

Comment: @raj240 I think the OS caused this problem. I also tried powershell and bat on my pc. they have the same problem when display is off. The code above works well on another old version of windows10. But I still dont know What is the difference between two environments..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the output.  The thread is not being "paused".

My reading is that the `println` call is **blocking** when the display is turned off.  Since it is blocking, the next `sleep` call is going to be delayed.

There is no way to solve this (i.e. change the behavior of writing to standard output) from within Java.  The blocking happens at the syscall level, and is done by the host operating system.

---

If you want to prevent the application from blocking like this, don't write directly to standard output / standard error if they are connected to a "sink" that *could* block.  If you write to a file in the local file system, it is pretty much guaranteed not to block.  Anything else could potentially block ... under certain circumstances.  So if it is an *absolute requirement* that the thread doesn't block, be careful what it writes to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I try to use a string value instead of println and check it in debug mode after step 4, but still get the same result. T_T

Comment: That's exactly what I would have predicted!!  It doesn't matter what method you use to write the output to standard output.  **The problem is on the Windows side.**  If you want to solve the problem, you need to do what I said starting with *"If you want to prevent the application from blocking like this ..."*

Comment: Thanks.  The code above works well on another older version of windows 10..maybe some power-saving settings has been updated..

Comment: Maybe it has.  I don't know.  Perhaps it would be worth asking on https://superuser.com if this is a known issue and if there is some Windows setting to that could be tweaked.